# Display items on webpage when found, not all at once

Tags: python, ajax, websocket, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I have a python web scraper that uses Beautiful Soup and python's mulitprocessing library.

I would  like to create a website that calls the scraper and displays the items that it returns. Here is the catch: even using multiprocessing, the script can take a long time to run and fetch the items I'm looking for. I don't want to wait for an AJAX request to complete and display all the values at once. I want to show each one individually as it is found.

Is this where websockets can be useful? Can I even use websockets if my scraper does multiprocessing? Or is there a better way altogether?

Ideally I'd like to use Javascript client side, if that makes a difference. But that is flexible.